# In 2sxc content module how to associate approval workflow for edits?

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I'm using 2sxc content module for DNN.

The page workflow only kicks in when i add a new 2sxc content module, however for any content edits the changes are published without any approval.

Can someone guide me to enable approval workflow even for content changes within the 2sxc content module?

Comment: If you mean the Evoq workflow stuff, this is currently not implemented.

Comment: Yes, I meant Evoq workflow. Is it planned for future release?

Comment: At the moment there is no sponsor. If one appears, it will happen quickly, otherwise not.